NextJs 13: Script de Next está presente en paginas donde no deberia
Tengo un problema y no logro entender de donde viene.
En mi componente MetaData estoy renderizando el componente Head de next/head con unos scripts en su interior
<Head>
  <Script... GTM />
  <Script... Zendesk/>
</Head>

Este componente es consumido por el GlobalLayout de mi aplicacion, y todas las paginas a excepcion de /booking estan wrappeadas con este GlobalLayout.
Si yo me encuentro en la pagina /unit, debo y veo los scripts correctamente, ya que esta pagina esta wrappeada con el layout.
Pero si yo me dirijo desde la pagina unit a la pagina booking, sigo viendo los scripts que tenia en el componente MetaData, cuando este componente ya no se está renderizando.
Cabe mencionar que en mi pagina booking tengo lo mismo que en MetaData, un Head que contiene otros scripts. Estos otros scripts nunca se renderizan, en cambio veo los scripts de metadata.
No se si tengo algun problema de persistencia de scripts que no logro ver, si por alguna razon usar dos veces el componente Head en la aplicacion puede traer algun problema... estoy bastante confundido.
Si yo elimino Head y en su lugar uso script normal de html, funciona. Pero quiero lograr entender porque los scripts siguen presentes en el codigo de otras paginas.
Gracias de antemano.

Estas usando next/script para cargar tus scripts? Muestra un ejemplo minimo de Script, estoy leyendo que si usas un meta ahi dentro debes usar la prop key para evitar duplicados

Lo que describes ocurre porque Next.js persiste el contenido de <Head> durante las transiciones de páginas para mejorar el rendimiento, lo que provoca que los scripts permanezcan incluso cuando se cambia de página.
En Next.js 13, no existe una configuración directa en next.config.js para desactivar esta persistencia de scripts. Sin embargo, puedes resolver el problema asegurándote de que los scripts se eliminen correctamente cuando cambias de página.
Sugiero:
Uso de next/script fuera de <Head>: Evita usar <Script> dentro de <Head>. En lugar de eso, coloca los scripts directamente en el componente o página donde los necesites. Esto garantizará que solo se carguen en las páginas deseadas.
Condicionalmente renderiza los scripts: Si debes mantener los scripts dentro de <Head>, puedes condicionalmente renderizarlos solo en las páginas que los necesiten. Así:

Limpiar los efectos secundarios manualmente: Puedes usar useEffect en el componente que maneja los scripts para limpiarlos cuando se cambie de página:

Componente Head separado para cada página: Asegúrate de que cada página tenga su propio <Head> sin compartir scripts globales en el GlobalLayout. Así, cada página gestionará sus scripts de manera independiente.
En resumen, el problema no se soluciona con una configuración específica de Next.js, sino gestionando cuidadosamente dónde y cuándo se cargan los scripts, usando una de las estrategias que te sugiero.

Estuve buscando sobre persistencia de scripts y no encontré nada, sabrias como desactivar eso? Es alguna config de next.config.js? Estoy usando Next 13

He cambiado mi respuesta, ahora la explico con mas detalle, y te paso 4 estrategias que puedes usar.

Muchas gracias! Tiene todo el sentido del mundo, voy a poder probar esto recien mañana pero me despejaste más de una duda al mismo tiempo.
